# High Paging file % Usage while memory is not full

Tags: sql-server, memory, memory-management, paging, perfmon

I was handed a server hosting SQL Server and I was asked to fined the causes of its bad performance problems.

While monitoring PerfMon I found that:

Paging file: **% Usage = 25%** average for 3 days.
Memory: Pages/sec > 1 average for 3 days.
What I know that if % Usage is > 2% then there is too much paging because of memory pressure and lack in memory space. However, if when I opened Resource Monitor, Memory tab, I found:

-26 GB in use (out of 32 GB total RAM)
-2 GB standby
-and **4 GB Memory free** !!!!!!

If there is 4 GB free memory why the paging?! and most importantly why it (paging %) is too high?!!

**Someone please explain this situation and how paging file % usage can be lowered to normal.**

Note that SQL Server Max. memory is set to 15GB

Comment: Are you sure that is the problem or is that just a guess? Have you looked into blocking, locking, wait stats or SQL statements with high I/O usage?

Answer (score 1):

Page file usage on its own isn't a major red flag. The OS will tend to use a page file even when there's plenty of RAM available, because it allows it to dump the relevant parts of memory from RAM when needed - don't think of the page file usage as memory *moved* from RAM to HDD - it's just a copy. All the accesses will still use RAM, the OS is simply preparing for a contingency - if it didn't have the memory pre-written to the page file, the memory requests would have to wait for "old" memory to be dumped before freeing the RAM for other uses.

Also, it seems you're a bit confused about how paging works. All user-space memory is *always* paged, this has nothing to do with the page file itself - it simply means you're using virtual memory. The metric you're looking for is Hard faults per second (**EDIT:** uh, I misread which one you're reading - Pages/sec *is* how many hard faults there are; still, the rest still applies), which tells you how often the OS had to actually *read* data from the page file. Even then, 1 per second is *extremely low*. You will rarely see anything until that number goes above fifty per sec or so, and much higher for SSDs (on my particular system, I can get thousands of hard faults with no noticeable memory lag - this varies a lot based on the actual HDD and your chipset and drivers).

Finally, there's way too many ways SQL Server performance can suffer. If you don't have a real DBA (or at least someone with plenty of DB experience), you're in trouble. Most of your lines of inquiry *will* lead you to dead-ends - something as complex and optimized as a DB engine is always hard to diagnose properly. Identify signs - is there a high CPU usage? Is there a high RAM usage? Are there queries with high I/O usage? Are there specific queries that are giving you trouble, or does the whole DB suffer? Are your indices and tables properly maintained? Those are just the very basics. Once you have some extra information like this, try [DBA.StackExchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - SO isn't really the right place to ask for DBA advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Just some shots in the dark really, might be a little random but I could hardly spot something straight away:

- might there be processes that select uselessly large data sets or run too frequent operations? (e.g. the awful app developers' practice to use `SELECT *` everywhere or get all data and then filter it on application level or run DB queries in loops instead of getting record sets once, etc.)
- is indexing proper? (e.g. are leaf elements employed where possible to reduce the key lookup operations, are heavy queries backed up with proper indices to avoid table & index scans etc.)
- how is data population managed? (e.g. is it possible that there are too many page splits due to improper clustered indices or parallel inserts, are there some index rebuilds taking place etc.)

Comment: @abutmah Of course it does - there really isn't a way for it not to. Perhaps you'd like to clarify what you're trying to say?

Comment: I've placed the same question on msdn forums:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9aebe231-5c9a-41a2-b89a-bb4081b76dd4/high-paging-file-usage-while-memory-is-not-full?forum=sqlkjmanageability

and Olaf (MVP) said that SQL Server don't utilize the Windows Page file